# Single-page-application with arcgis maps

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, arcgis, esri

In my single-page-application I'm using durandaljs and knockout, but durandal and arcgis maps are incompatible, because arcgis maps use dojo(durandaljs doesnt work with dojo, require js ony). Which simple spa-framework I can use with esri arcgis maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Leaflet. See https://github.com/esri/esri-leaflet
It's still evolving quickly but it is very promising.

Answer (score -1):

You can use better openlayers. (Open source)

OpenLayers makes it easy to put a dynamic map in any web page.

Here is the url:

http://www.openlayers.org

Comment: Unfortunally, i cant do it, because application should work with arcgis server

Comment: Can you not your data remove to opensource database postgis and geoserver?

Comment: Hm, i read about it later, but in this case i must use arcgis. This is the simple application for demonstrate javascript and arcgis maps(we always work with aecgis, but usually its wpf or silverlight application)